# Without check constraint how Bigquery validate data?

Tags: google-bigquery, check-constraints

We don't have application running on server,

so all the logic need to be done on `Bigquery`.

I know `Microsoft SQL Server` have `check constraint` like:

```
CREATE TABLE MyCleanJapanClient (
    Phone varchar(255) CHECK (Phone LIKE '+81%'),
    Email varchar(255) CHECK (Email LIKE '%_@__%.__%')
);
```

So when I use query like

```
INSERT INTO `MyCleanJapanClient` 
SELECT
  Phone AS Phone,
  Email AS Email
FROM `YourDirtyJapanClient`;
```

I got expected error `The INSERT statement conflicted with the CHECK constraint`

But with Bigquery,

how can I validate data like using check constraint?

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, there is no equivalent to the T-SQL dialect "CHECK" capability in BigQuery.  What you can do is use the Data Quality capabilities and periodically validate/detect whether or not your table rows meet quality considerations.  See:  https://cloud.google.com/dataplex/docs/auto-data-quality-overview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by @Kolban, there is no equivalent to the T-SQL dialect "CHECK" capability in BigQuery.

You can use the Data Quality capabilities and periodically validate/detect whether or not your table rows meet quality considerations.

For more information you can refer to the following [link](https://cloud.google.com/dataplex/docs/auto-data-quality-overview).